# erlang lager_syslog driver failure

Tags: erlang, rebar

I'm trying to use `lager_syslog` in my project but it seems like a driver is missing.

This is in my `rebar.conf`:

```
    {deps, [
       ...
       {lager_syslog, {git, "https://github.com/basho/lager_syslog.git", {branch, master}}}
    ]}.
```

My test handler:

```
    {lager_syslog_backend, ["test", local1, info]},
```

The error:

```
19:29:09.981 [error] Lager failed to install handler {lager_syslog_backend,{"test",local1}} into lager_event, retrying later : {error,
   {{shutdown,
     {failed_to_start_child,
      syslog,
      "could not load driver syslog_drv: \"cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory\""}},
    {syslog_app,
     start,
     [normal,
      []]}}}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks to **Kenneth Lakin** who answered my question in mailing list

IIRC, rebar3 moved the port compiler out to a rebar3 plugin, rather than
packing it in with the core project. From what I've seen, rebar2
projects that relied on it will fail to load their port drivers.

Add

```
{overrides,
  [{override, syslog, [
    {plugins, [pc]},
    {artifacts, ["priv/syslog_drv.so"]},
    {provider_hooks, [
      {post,
        [
        {compile, {pc, compile}},
        {clean, {pc, clean}}
        ]
      }]
    }
  ]}
]}.
```

to a rebar.conf in your project, clean, and rebuild. (The syslog project
is where lager_syslog's port driver lives.)

See also: https://github.com/blt/port_compiler#use-with-existing-dependency